# doc-view display pages side by side

Tags: emacs, docview

Is it possible to have doc view display two pages (side by side), instead of just one? For example,I'd like to see pg 15 and pg 16 at the same time.

Thanks,
Lalit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think follow-mode will work on doc-view documents.  I encourage you to report this as a "bug / feature request".  In the mean time, you'll have to do it by hand: `C-x 3 C-x o next`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to comment yet, but to add page-flipping for dual Pages to Stefans answer manually, do his setup
C-x 3 C-x o n

and then record a keyboard macro that will flip two pages for both frames.

Macro definition: Execute following key sequence:
C-x ( n n C-x o n n C-x o C-x )

Execute  macro with 'C-x e' and repeat execution just with 'e'

You can then save the macro for the current emacs session (so it doesn't affect other emacs instances, at least for me, but I don't use emacsclient!) by binding the macro to a key combo (e.g. C-9)
C-x C-k b C-9

Now repeat process for 'page up', bind it to C-8, and you can easily flip through your two-column pdf =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about docview in particular, but you can use `follow-mode` to view two (or more) pages side by side of any kind of buffer.

Try:

```
M-x follow-delete-other-windows-and-split RET
```

*EDIT:* This typically work for all kinds of buffers -- however, "doc-view" is such a special kind of animal so follow-mode does not, currently, work for it.

Comment: Thanks for this! It doesn't work for doc-view but good to know about!